# Apache Timeout directive not working?

Tags: apache, tcp, timeout, connection

I have configured /etc/apache2/apache2.conf with Timeout 5 instead of the default 300. So I understand it should close an incoming connection after 5 seconds of inactivity.

But I make a telnet localhost 80 , wait for 5 and more seconds, and nothing happens. A netstat -na tells me the connection is still ESTABLISHED. I left the connection about 5 minutes and still nothing happened.

Any clues why Apache is not cutting the connection? Or am I misunderstanding the Timeout directive? And in that case, which one should I look for?

Comment: This may belong on ServerFault.  However, isn't the timeout for HTTP keepalives?

Comment: question now asked on servfault, please close this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/78193/apache-timeout-directive-not-working